# List of all items stored in kernel

Tags: variable-definitions, kernel

In Matlab, there is a window on the side that contains all of the variables stored in the workspace.

Is there something equivalent in Mathematica? 
I am imagining a command kind of like DownValues or OwnValues but for the entire kernel. Some command that will print out all of the rules stored in the system.

Comment: For ``"Global`*"`` this might be workable and I think people have done that already on this site (search for stuff related to that) but if you include like package symbols or system symbols it'd simply be too much to look at.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Could you please provide a link? I tried a couple searches like: 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Global%60*%22
But I didn't quite find what you were talking about

Comment: Also, I tried OwnValues["Global`*"], but it doesn't work.